# Book about a traveling salesman who discovers a buried UFO and finds a portal in his front door

Tags: story-identification, books

Book about a traveling salesman that discovers a buried UFO, he gets home and finds a portal in his front door. He meets some aliens and exchanges a gravitational vehicle for paint. In both exchanges it was not the object what was exchanged but the concepts. Excellent book indeed.

Answer (score 19):

This sounds a lot like "The Big Front Yard," a story by Clifford D. Simak, but some details don't match.

See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Front_Yard) for a good summary and the great cover art for the October 1968 issue of *ASF*.  It won the [1959 Best Novelette Hugo.](http://fancyclopedia.org/1959-best-novelette-hugo)  See also the book on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16396737-the-big-front-yard).

The main character, Hiram Taine is a tinkerer and trader, not a travelling salesman.  (He does things like buy antiques and fix them and resell them.)   He lives in a nice town and is known locally as someone who can sell anything to anyone.

His house gets taken over by aliens who turn it into a dimensional gate. His back door is as it always was, but his front door now opens onto an apparently uninhabited alien world.  His dog becomes telepathic.

He and a friend and the dog explore and run into a small party of humanoid aliens riding on anti-gravity saddles -- they look like people ridding saddles, but without a horse underneath. They just float there.  He's able to communicate through the dog and discoverers that it's a trading party.

But the aliens don't trade things, they trade ideas. What ideas do humans have that they could trade? The man notices that the aliens' things are drably colored and asks them if they know about paint. They don't, so he dickers with them and trades the idea of paint for the idea of anti-gravity.

Comment: That would have been my answer, too. :-)

Comment: The swapping of _concept_ rather than _product_ was the trigger for me; I think this story was unique in suggesting this for interstellar commerce.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin I'm pretty sure it was first. I do recall the idea being used again, later, though I don't recall the stories.

Comment: That was the book. I read it at the Perry Castaneda Library when I studied at UT at Austin.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the correct answer.
I read it in 1980’s and was thrilled by the situation and the bartering system, not things but concepts.
This book I have had it in mind for years, now I can re-read it again.

Comment: @Edo You can *accept* an answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left. This marks the answer as correct and gives an extra thank you to the answerer's reputation.